is it possible to extract the co-ordination number vs simulation time from VASP AIMD calculations?
is there any script or software available for extracting the co-ordination number for each step from AIMD results.

Check Ovito. https://www.ovito.org/manual/reference/pipelines/modifiers/coordination_analysis.html
